# How to Generate a VEX document using a SBOM file?

Tags: security, owasp, devsecops

I was trying with a tool called vexy github: https://github.com/madpah/vexy, but no help.

I tried installing VEXY and for some reason it just does not let me scan the sbom file,

```
vexy --in-file /home/deepak/Desktop/bom.json
```

i used the above line to scan, does not work.

Answer (score 0):

A full vexy CLI example follows:

`vexy --config vexy.yml --in-file target/sbom.json --format json --output target/sbom.vex-vexy.json`

The `vexy.yml` in my case is just minimal:

```yaml
sources:
  osv:
```

How to configure it is documented at https://vexy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html.

An alternative to generating VEX from CyclonDX SBOM is OWASP dep-scan: https://github.com/owasp-dep-scan/dep-scan. It is much more sophisticated than vexy. It's from the same author who also created and maintains `cdxgen`.